# COPY files from src folder into nginx when docker being built in gitlab

Tags: docker, gitlab

I am trying to copy files from a src folder on the root of my repo into the www folder within a nginx image, and perhaps the php-fpm folder too (if needed?) when it is being built and sent to my registry. I am using gitlab for CI when runs this when I commit to the repo, which currently works fine, but lacks the copying of files.

in the root of the repo is:

```
    .gitlab-ci.yaml
    /php-fpm
    /nginx
    /src
```

my gitlab-ci.yml file:

```yaml
    image: docker:stable
    
    services:
    - docker:18-dind
    variables:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://localhost:2376
    
    php:
    
      before_script:
        - docker login gitlab.domain.com:5050 -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
      script:
        - docker build -t gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/site/php:7.2-fpm ./php-fpm
        - docker push gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/site/php:7.2-fpm
    
    nginx:
    
      before_script:
        - docker login gitlab.domain.com:5050 -u ${CI_REGISTRY_USER} -p ${CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD}
      script:
        - docker build -t gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/site/nginx:stable ./nginx
        - docker push gitlab.domain.com:5050/project/site/nginx:stable
```

The images currently get added to the repo fine, but I need to copy the /src files in.

In /nginx is a Dockerfile:

```
    FROM nginx:1.18.0-alpine
    COPY conf/default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

In /nginx/conf:

```
    server {
        listen 80;
        index index.php index.html;
        root /var/www/html/public;
        client_max_body_size 32M;
    
        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.php?$args;
        }
    
        location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/sock/php-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        }
    }
```

In /php-fpm/entrypoint.sh (Do I need to copy the /src files here also?)

```
    #!/bin/sh 
    WORKDIR="/var/www/html"
    chown -R www-data:www-data $WORKDIR
    cd $WORKDIR
    
    php artisan cache:clear
    php artisan route:clear
    php artisan config:cache
    
    php-fpm -F
```

In /php-fpm/Dockerfile

```
    FROM php:7.2-fpm-alpine
    RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo_mysql
    COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
    WORKDIR /var/www/html
    CMD ["/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh"]
```

In /php-fpm/php-fpm.d/php-fpm-www.conf

```
    error_log = /proc/self/fd/2
    
    [www]
    user = www-data
    group = www-data
    
    listen.owner = www-data
    listen.group = www-data
    listen = /sock/php-fpm.sock
    
    pm = dynamic
    pm.max_children = 5
    pm.start_servers = 2
    pm.min_spare_servers = 1
    pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```